# Remove gloss/gradient effect from Navigation/Tab bars

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I would like to remove the gradient effect that occurs in the `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar`. The following picture shows an example tab bar using the custom UIColor of 7/29/88 (RGB), set using `setTintColor:color` and as you can see, the tab bar has a gloss in the top half of the bar.

[image]

How do I remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. However you can use custom background images. Check `UIAppearance` documentation

Comment: I should have ascertained this from the documentation - somehow convinced myself that I had done something wrong! Thanks for the reference. Cheers.

Comment: Check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6. The other option is to use PrettyKit, find on Github.

Comment: it is possible to easily eliminate the standard fill effect on both `UITabBar` and `UINavigationBar`. See my answer.

Comment: `UIAppearance` is simply a convenience to set specific propetry values for all instances that fall within the appearance proxy's scope. Anything that can be done with `UIAppearance` can be done without it. I agree that most people will want to use `UIAppearance` but it is most definitely optional and not required to answer this specific question.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on your definition of "remove". In iOS 6.x (didn't test iOS 4/5) the following works.

```
// this will show a tab bar with a solid background color
tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage new];
tabBar.backroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

// this will show a navigation bar with a solid background color
[navBar setBakgroundImage:[UIImage new]
            forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]];
navBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
navBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
navBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

I remove the gradient effect from my Navigation Bar, you can try this code and see if its works for you too.

```
//First, create your own Navigation Bar Class, and add this to your init method.

self.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"]];

//Add this to your DrawRect method
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"]]; 
   //If you want a plain color change this

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([color CGColor]));
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
}
```